# Calculate the path of the direct wave

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

A small piezoelectric transducer (T) excited by an electrical signal, emits spherical waves equal to 34kHz. A detector (D) receives these waves placed at a fixed distance, L=30cm, from the emitter. The emitted waves can reflect in a plane (P) before arriving at the receiver. This registers an interference between the waves that arrive directly and the waves reflected. The propagation speed of the waves is 340 m/s. In the figure, the set T - D can move perpendicularly to P. For what distance does the first minimum occur in the intensity registered by D?

[image]

Attempt:

$TD=30cm$

$f=34$kHz = $34 \cdot 10^3$ Hz

$V=340$ m/s $=340 \cdot 10^2$ cm/s

So I took T' as the virtual center of emission of the reflected waves. From the propagation speed and frequency, I saw that it deals with ultrasound waves, for which reflection with inversion must be observed. I was only able to calculate the path of the direct wave and bent wave. How could I proceed to resolve this issue?

answer: $3.9$cm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  using Pythagoras, express $TE$ in terms of $a$ where $E$ is the point on $P$ such that $TE$ =$ED$.

Find the wavelength of the signal and the number of wavelengths that fit in $TD$.

Decide whether $TE+ED$ must be half a wavelength or a full wavelength longer than $TD$.

Write your first expression equal to the new distance and calculate $a$.